# How to update a StatisticEntity on each PUT request to API Plateform

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I have 3 entity on API plateform (see shema below).

My goal is that at each PUT, POST or DELETE request to reviews, the linked stats about the mainObject gets increments.

Does anyone know an elegant solution ?

#### mainObject (Item rated)

- ID, *int UUID*
- title, *char*
- type, *int*
- year, *int*
- user, *int KEY users*
- created, *date*

#### mainObjectStats (Stats about item One to One per mainObjects)

- ID, *int UUID*
- mainObjectID, *int KEY mainObject*
- countReviews, *char*
- countTotalRatingsStar, *int*

#### reviews (Many to One review(s) per mainObject)

- ID, *int UUID*
- mainObjectID, *int KEY mainObject*
- userID, *int KEY users*
- body, *char*
- ratings
- created, *date*

I try to write a custom Normalizer but I couldnt achieve the expected result.

What I want is that :

1. someone rate a mainObject
2. the stats about the mainObject get automatically update
3. so that I can display stats without having to fetch and group by all reviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for event subscriber.
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/

Here is an exemple :

```
final class mainObjectSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{


    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
         // Add all events you want to track here
        return [
            KernelEvents::VIEW => [
                'changeStats', EventPriorities::POST_VALIDATE
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function changeStats(ViewEvent $event)
    {
        $mainObject = $event->getControllerResult();
        $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();
        $apiOperationName = $event->getRequest()->get('_api_operation_name');

        // Change this if according to which operation you want to track, remove operation name control if needed

        if (!($mainObject instanceof MainObject) || Request::METHOD_POST !== $method && $apiOperationName !== MainObject::API_OPERATION_MAINOBJECT_ADD) {
            return;
        }

        // Do your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent ! Excatly what I was looking for.

I have just one other question. How do you choose between those strategies to make custom logic ? Is there any adavantage/disadavantage of using one of them.

- Creating Custom Operations and Controllers 
   (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/)
- The Event System 
   (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/)
- State Processors
   https://api-platform.com/docs/core/state-processors/

Comment: That's a really good question. I mean, since some of them are generic like the one i linked, and controller can be very specific to an api operation only, it depend on which kind of usecase you have. 
Depending on when you want to perform the action, before persist, after flush etc... 
But to be honest, i find it sometime confusing too haha